# Just a quick question about adding quotation marks in python and ACSII

Tags: python, excel, csv

Hopefully just a quick question...

By using this bit of code in python below, will the Quotation come back as  ASCII 34/22 in hex?

I'm asking this question because I added commas to my CSV in excel using \”@\” and my strings came back as extended ascii characters, 148, or 94 in hex.

https://www.asciitable.com/

If anyone knows why excel does this, I would be really grateful!

```
df['Address'] = '"' + df['Address'].astype(str) + '"'
```

Comment: When you say "double comma" do you actually mean "double quotation mark"? A comma  is , and double quotation mark is "

Comment: whoops, you are right! I have edited the question! Sorry!